# MySQLの複数のバックアップデータをリカバリーする方法

Tags: mysql

MySQLの複数のバックアップデータを一度にリカバリーする方法をお尋ねしたいです。

mysqldumpコマンドを使って、いくつかのテーブルの保存をとりました。
ここでは仮に以下のようにしておきます。

```
mysqldump -u root -pxxxxxxxxxx mytable > mytable.2019-01-30.sql
```

この方法をつかって、定期的にバックアップをとっておりました。
ただ途中でtableのサイズが大きくなりますので、バックアップをとった後は、drop tableを使って削除して、また新たにcreate table mytableを作っています。

結果として、
mytable.2019-01-30.sql
mytable.2019-01-23.sql
mytable.2019-01-16.sql
を作成したとしてください。

リカバリーの方法としては、

```
mysql -u root -pxxxxxxxxxx　DATABASE < mytable.2019-01-30.sql
```

でバックアップデータを回復させることは知っております。

現在困っていることは、

```
mysql -u root -pxxxxxxxxxx　DATABASE < mytable.2019-01-30.sql
mysql -u root -pxxxxxxxxxx　DATABASE < mytable.2019-01-23.sql
mysql -u root -pxxxxxxxxxx　DATABASE < mytable.2019-01-16.sql
```

と行ったときに、最後（？）のtableしかリカバリーされないことです。（他2つのtableは消去（？）されてしまいます。）

table名が同じで、中身のstructureも同じtableを「追加」でリカバリーして、3つのsqlファイルを1つのtableでリカバリーさせる方法はございますでしょうか?

具体的には、
mytable.2019-01-30.sql
mytable.2019-01-23.sql
mytable.2019-01-16.sql
のファイル内容をすべてmytableに再収納させたいです。

ファイルをリカバリーさせて、renameでtable名を変更しておき、最後に２つのmytableを結合させる方法はしっておりますが、復元させないといけないファイル数が多いため、別の方法を探しています。

もしご存知の方がおられましたら、ご教授をお願いします。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: バックアップしたファイルに、”DROP TABLE”文が有るために最後に実行したリカバリーデータだけになってしまっていると思います。

Comment: リカバリのコマンドは`mysqldump`ではなく、`mysql -u root -p????? DB < FILE.sql`ではありませんか？それとも今回答があるようにバックアップ時のことについて聞きたいのでしょうか？

Comment: すみません。ご指摘の通り、コマンドを間違えました。修正しておきます。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ダンプ結果はテキスト形式でSQL文が書かれていますので、一度中身を覗いてみることをおすすめします。

`mysqldump`をデフォルトで実行すると、ダンプしたSQLにはテーブル作成前に予め`drop table`文が挿入されているので、複数回リストアを実行した場合にも最新分しか反映されないようになります。

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `comments`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `comments` (
```

これを回避するには、(二回目以降の)バックアップ時に`--skip-add-drop-table`オプションを付けるとよいでしょう。

ただし重複するデータがある場合をケアする必要があるかもしれません (私もMySQLは最近使い始めたばかりなので、あまり自信はありません)。

参考:
[4.5.4 mysqldump — データベースバックアッププログラム](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/mysqldump.html)

> ```
> --skip-add-drop-table
>     DROP TABLE ステートメントを CREATE TABLE ステートメントの前に追加しない
> ```

Comment: バックアップ済みのファイルは（*.sql）エディタで開き"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `xxxxxxx`;"を削除してからリカバリーを実行すると良いでしょう、又、データのkey が重複すると Duplicate エラーになり リカバリーが止まります。

Comment: cubick様、yyz様、ありがとうございます。sqlフィルの中身を確認したところ、確かにDrop tableのコマンドがありました。これが原因だったんですね。オプションをつけるなり、yyz様が指摘しているような方法で対処したいと思います。有難うございました。

Comment: 今回はmysqldumpのときに[--skip-add-drop-table]オプションをつけていませんでしたので、プログラムで該当する部分を取り除きました。あと今回は「mytable」という名のテーブル一つをdumpしていましたが、複数のテーブルを同一のsqlファイルにdumpする場合は、やはり該当する箇所がsqlファイル内に複数箇所ありますので、すべてを取り除かないとDrop tableが発動されてしまいますんで、お気をつけください。